# Implements Interface only if exists?

Tags: php, oop, interface

I'm trying to find a way to implement an Interface only when this Interface is available.

The Interface in question is

```
PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module\WidgetInterface
```

From Prestashop. It's used in a module.

The thing is, in order to be compatible with multiple version of Prestashop, the code must handle the case where `WidgetInterface` does not exists.

I was thinking in testing the existence of the interface and import it after, like this:

```
if (interface_exists('PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module\WidgetInterface')) {
    use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module\WidgetInterface
} else {
    interface WidgetInterface {}
}
```

But of course, it's not possible to use `use` inside a if statement.

I then tried to do some try/catch, but that's the same issue (too bad it's not Python).

How can I do to `implements WidgetInterface` only when available?

Comment: Reflection comes to mind.

Comment: Yeah! I'm a bit lost. I'm certainly not the only one in this situation! ...

Comment: How about instead of `use`, try [`class_alias()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-alias.php) inside your `if()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't implement an interface dynamically, like you say, but you can write your own interface and only `require` it if the other does not exist.

Ie: your interface would be something like `widget_interface.php`, or whatever you want to call it, as long as it's not PSR-0/4 compliant, or autoloaded in whatever way you normally do.

```
<?php    

namespace PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module;

/**
 * This is the replacement interface, using the same namespace as the Prestashop one
 */
interface WidgetInterface
{
}
```

Then, in your class, you can do the following:

```
<?php

namespace App;

if (!interface_exists('\PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module\WidgetInterface')) {
    require __DIR__ . '/path/to/widget_interface.php';
}

class WhateverClass implements \PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Module\WidgetInterface
{

}
```

Your replacement interface will only be loaded if the Prestashop one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

True, you can't put `use` inside an `if` block, but `use` merely sets up an alias for the class. It doesn't attempt to load the class. So it can safely be outside the `if` block.

And you *can* define the class or interface itself inside an `if`.

[This](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/3c3db2f14a8d8dc96581560f8a24ce2f866eabda/src/Symfony/Contracts/EventDispatcher/EventDispatcherInterface.php) is how Symfony dealt with this exact issue, inheriting from an interface that may not exist:

```
namespace Symfony\Contracts\EventDispatcher;

use Psr\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface as PsrEventDispatcherInterface;

if (interface_exists(PsrEventDispatcherInterface::class)) {
    interface EventDispatcherInterface extends PsrEventDispatcherInterface
    {
        public function dispatch($event);
    }
} else {
    interface EventDispatcherInterface
    {
        public function dispatch($event);
    }
}
```

Personally, to keep things clean and contained in one spot, I would define your own interface like this that inherits from the `PrestaShop` interface if available or else provides its own implementation, and then have your class inherit from that.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this for a Laravel app to support both versions 9 and 10. This isn't exactly the same situation, since an interface exists in both versions. But, rather than create a shim interface or deal with loading files I just did this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;              // 9.0 interface
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;    // 10.0 interface

if (!interface_exists(ValidationRule::class)) {
    class_alias(Rule::class, ValidationRule::class);
}

class MyRule implements ValidationRule {
    // ...
}
```

Now when I refer to `ValidationRule` it will either be the actual interface in 10.0, or the alias in 9.0.

I think it violates PSR-2 or 12 to have non-class code in the file, but I'm not a stickler for rules when they get in the way.